# ImageIO не подгружает файл из ресурсов?

Tags: java

Работаю с tray для загрузки иконки использую,

```
 Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/images/16x16.gif"));
 TrayIcon trayIcon = new java.awt.TrayIcon(image);
```

но возникает ошибка

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

Указывая на строку `Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/images/16x16.gif"));`

путь правильный.
Что может быть не так ?

Comment: Дело не в ImageIO. Метод `getResource` возвращает `null` так как не может найти ресурс.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а как ему его прописать ?

Comment: Если ресурсы ищутся в jar, то прежде всего стоит убедиться, что они туда упакованы. Если не в jar, то убедиться, что каталог `resources` попадает в CLASSPATH.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev CLASSPATH вы имеете ввиду в "переменные и среды" ? Сейчас ресурсы в папке с проектом не jar.

Comment: Нет, я имею ввиду пути, в которых виртуальная машина будет искать классы и ресурсы. Неважно, как именно эти пути задаются.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вы правы дело было в пути следовало прописать не "/resources/images/16x16.gif" а "/images/16x16.gif"

Comment: Рад, что помог.